# Log ActiveJob APM Traces with DataDog

Tags: resque, rails-activejob, datadog

my configuration is:

```
Datadog.configure do |c|
  c.tracer enabled: Rails.env.production? || ENV['DD_TRACE_ENABLED'] == 'true'
  c.tracer analytics_enabled: true

  c.use :rails, service_name: 'rails'
  c.use :resque, workers: ApplicationJob.subclasses + ApplicationWorker.subclasses, service_name: 'resque'
  c.use :http, service_name: 'http'
  c.use :redis, service_name: 'redis'
end
```

Where:

- The `ApplicationJob` signature is `class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base`
- The `ApplicationWorker` is used as a parent class for vanilla Resque
  classes.

I'm not getting any errors, but I **am** seeing the subclasses of `ApplicationWorker` in the DataDog dashboard for the APM traces but *not* the `ApplicationJob` subclasses.

From the documentation I've found this is the correct way to configure `activeJob` tracing when it uses `resque`, but I haven't found such great documentation on the subject.

Comment: Have you tried adding `c.diagnostics.debug = true` to see if there are any useful debug messages?

Answer (score 0):

After reading this documentation, https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/setup_overview/setup/ruby/#resque, did you try making the options a hash with curly braces surrounding? Options is specified as being a hash. So everything after `c.use :resque,`  should be a **hash**.